# Error al crear una tabla con 3 llaves compuestas SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Solicito de su ayuda estoy creando mi tabla **TK_BT_SLAS** con 3 llaves compuestas al momento de ejecutar el script tengo el siguiente error en **SQL Server 2014**:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table
>   'TK_CT_SERVICES' that match the referencing column list in the foreign
>   key 'FK_SLA_SERVICES'.

**Script SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE TK_CT_AREAS (
    TK_CT_AREAS_ID varchar (10) PRIMARY KEY (TK_CT_AREAS_ID),
    NAME varchar (100) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE TK_CT_PRIORITIES (
    TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID varchar (3) PRIMARY KEY (TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID),
    NAME varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    CONTENT varchar (250) NOT NULL, 
);

CREATE TABLE TK_CT_SERVICES (
    TK_CT_SERVICES_ID varchar (3) NOT NULL,
    NAME varchar (20) NOT NULL,
    CONTENT varchar (250) NOT NULL,
    TK_CT_AREAS_ID varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (TK_CT_SERVICES_ID, TK_CT_AREAS_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SERVICE_AREA FOREIGN KEY (TK_CT_AREAS_ID) REFERENCES TK_CT_AREAS(TK_CT_AREAS_ID),
);

-- Esta es la tabla a la cual le quiero crear las 3 llaves compuestas

CREATE TABLE TK_BT_SLAS (
    SLA INT NOT NULL,
    TK_CT_SERVICES_ID varchar (3) NOT NULL,
    TK_CT_AREAS_ID varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID varchar (3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TK_CT_SERVICES_ID, TK_CT_AREAS_ID, TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SLA_SERVICES FOREIGN KEY (TK_CT_SERVICES_ID) REFERENCES TK_CT_SERVICES(TK_CT_SERVICES_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SLA_AREA FOREIGN KEY (TK_CT_AREAS_ID) REFERENCES TK_CT_SERVICES(TK_CT_AREAS_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SLA_PRIORITY FOREIGN KEY (TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID) REFERENCES TK_CT_PRIORITIES(TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID), 
 );
```

Comment: creo que es pq la primary key en la tabla services es compuesta. entonces puede tener valores repetidos.. pero es solo una conjetura (la proxima vez, pon nombres que sean faciles de seguir... ;) )

Comment: Al ejecutar el script la tabla **TK_CT_SERVICES** no me genero error entonces con esa no se tiene ningún problema, el problema esta con **TK_BT_SLAS**

Comment: si, pero el problema es al querer conectarte a la clave de arriba... si la clave primaria son dos campos, en tu tabla hija, deberian estar los dos campos y hacer referencia a que son un constrain a la otra... o no? si no, como identifica a que registro del padre va a parar?

Comment: Una foreign key referencia una primary key de otra tabla. No es una parte, es toda la primary key. Tal y como indican en el comentario, el references debe apuntar a TODOS los campos que conforman la llave primaria en la tabla referenciada.

Comment: @gbianchi Ya veo porque sucede, que solución me puedes dar para poder ejecutar el script asi como esta

Comment: Para que no te marque error has lo que te comentan apunta cada llave a su respetiva tabla para que no te marque ese error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de ir y venir logre solucionar mi problema gracias al comentario @Alfabravo apuntando el references a todos los campos que conforman la llave primaria en la tabla referenciada de esta manera

```
CREATE TABLE TK_BT_SLAS (
    SLA INT NOT NULL,
    TK_CT_SERVICES_ID varchar (3) NOT NULL,
    TK_CT_AREAS_ID varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID varchar (3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TK_CT_SERVICES_ID, TK_CT_AREAS_ID, TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SLA_SERVICES FOREIGN KEY (TK_CT_SERVICES_ID, TK_CT_AREAS_ID) REFERENCES TK_CT_SERVICES(TK_CT_SERVICES_ID, TK_CT_AREAS_ID),    
    CONSTRAINT FK_SLA_PRIORITY FOREIGN KEY (TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID) REFERENCES TK_CT_PRIORITIES(TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID), 
 );
```